# Convert java.lang.String to android.nfc.Tag

Tags: java, android, android-intent, tags, nfc

I have a current set of codes which works fine, which is:
[image]

I wanted to create a new project without newIntent and stuff and here is my codes:
[image]

and after some debugging, i found out what the **currentTag** contains which is:
[image]

from my understanding, currentTag is the details of the nfc chip.
I am trying to do the same to my new project without any success.
Would appreciate any help or pointers as im new to NFC. Thanks!

Edit: This is the NFCTagHelper Class:

```
public class NfcTagHelper {
private static final int PAGE_FOR_WRITE_CHECK = 4;
private static final int PAGE_FOR_READ_RESULT = 6;
private static final byte FAILURE_RESULT = 0x22;
public static final byte TAG_LOST_RESULT = 0x33;
public static final byte UNKNOW_ERROR_RESULT=0x44;
private static final String TAG = NfcTagHelper.class.getSimpleName();
public boolean writeToTag(Tag tag,byte[] lockID) {
    boolean result=false;
    MifareUltralight mifareUltralight = MifareUltralight.get(tag);
    if (mifareUltralight==null) {
        Log.e("NfcTagHelper", "This tag don't support to wirte page");
        return false;
    }else {
        try {
            mifareUltralight.connect();
            mifareUltralight.writePage(PAGE_FOR_WRITE_CHECK,lockID);
            result =true;
        }catch (Exception exception) {
            result=false;
            Log.e("NfcTagHelper", "write Error:", exception);
        }finally {
            try {
                mifareUltralight.close();
            }catch (Exception exception) {
                result=false;
                Log.e("NfcTagHelper", "Exception:", exception);
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
public byte readFromTag(Tag tag) {
    byte result=0x00;
    MifareUltralight mifareUltralight = MifareUltralight.get(tag);
    if (mifareUltralight==null) {
        Log.e("NfcTagHelper", "This tag don't support to wirte page");
    }else {
        try {
            mifareUltralight.connect();
            byte[]payload = mifareUltralight.readPages(PAGE_FOR_READ_RESULT);
            result= payload[0];
        }catch (TagLostException tagLostException) {
            result = TAG_LOST_RESULT;
        }
        catch (Exception exception) {
            Log.e("NfcTagHelper", "Read Error:", exception);
            result=UNKNOW_ERROR_RESULT;
        }finally {
            try {
                mifareUltralight.close();
            }catch (Exception exception) {
                Log.e("NfcTagHelper", "Read Exception:", exception);
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: what is `NfcTagHelper` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intents are Android's main means of inter-process communication. The Android NFC stack (NFC system service process) delivers information about discovered tags to your activity (app process) by sending NFC discovery intents (`NDEF_DISCOVERED`, `TECH_DISCOVERED`, and `TAG_DSICOVERED`) or through the reader-mode callback (activity lifecycle callback).

Consequently, there is no way to obtain a `Tag` object without processing either an NFC discovery intent (for instance, received through `onNewIntent`) or the ReaderCallback (`onTagDiscovered`).

Note that NFC discovery events are basically user-triggered (i.e. a user taps a tag to trigger such an event). If you want to process a tag upon pressing a button, you have a second user-triggered event, which you should not expect to happen synchonized to each other. Moreover, you should not expect the user to keep touching the tag for a longer time (not only because that's difficult to handle for the user, but also the handset and the tag communicate over a wireless interface and communication might get interrupted).

The best approach would be to, upon the user clicking the button, switch into a state (e.g. set a flag) where you accept NFC discovery events. Then, upon completing tag IO, you could clear that flag to switch back into a state where you no longer accept new tags.